# Important pythonic concepts/ questions that a intermediate python developer should know/ answer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am an intermediate python developer who has been working with python from past 18 months. However i am still unsure about my level of expertise with the language i.e how closely i know Python. I would like to know that what are some of the most important concepts or questions related to python that i should be familiar with.

Specifically, what are some of the more common modules or practices that every Python programmer should learn about once they fully grasp the syntax and logical flow of Python?

Thanks

Comment: Worth to read/watch: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/ http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html http://nedbatchelder.com/text/iter.html http://blog.habnab.it/blog/2013/07/21/python-packages-and-you/

Comment: @Harshal if you enjoy learning from video check this [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OSGv2VnC0go] idiomatic python vid which is rly interesting imho